# Several instances of Netbeans on Win 32 platform

Tags: java

It it possible to have several instances of Netbeans running as you can with Visual Studio on Win 32 platform? I can just fire up one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a excellent post by Tushar about multiple instance of Netbeans IDE -> [Opening Multiple netbeans ide](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/12/opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances.html)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMultipleIdeInstances) for details.